# Is it possible to change href of a link when mobile version?

Tags: javascript, href

I would like to change **href** target in a mobile version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    document.getElementById("myAnchor").href = "mobile-url";   //change url
    document.getElementById("myAnchor").target = "_blank";     //change target
}
```

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3514784/2792083) to find "the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery"